# How to improve parameters in method TypeScript/Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have function that can has some parameters:

```
public find(
    cadnum: string,
    pagesize: number,
    startid?: string
  ): Observable<any> {
    let url = "";

    if (cadnum) {
       url+= "?cadnum=" + cadnum;  
    }

     if (pagesize) {
       url+= "&pagesize=" + pagesize;  
    }

 if (startid) {
       url+= "&startid=" + startid;  
    }

    return this.httpClient.get(url);
}
```

As you can see I shoud check all parameters and concate string URL...

How to improve this part, because I have more parameters

Comment: Fixed, sorry, typo

Comment: Got it! Anyways, are you using Angular's HTTPClient?

Comment: Yes, I use httpClient Angular

Comment: You can use `URLSearchParams` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Object as parameter and then loop on its attributes

```js
// Convert an object to HttpParams
// Function I picked up from JHipster :p
const createRequestOption = (params?: any): HttpParams => {
    let options: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    if (params) {
        Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
            if (req[key] != null) {
                options = options.set(key, req[key]);
            }
        });
    }
    return options;
};

public find(params? :any): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'http://...';
    const options = createRequestOption(params);
    return this.httpClient.get(url, { params: options});
}
```

If you want to strong-type, it should also work with

```js
public find(params: {
    cadnum: string,
    pagesize: number,
    startid?: string
}): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'http://...';
    const options = createRequestOption(params);
    return this.httpClient.get(url, { params: options});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above can be simplified as the following:

```
return this.httpClient.get(url, { 
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  params: {
    cadnum, 
    pagesize,
    startid,
  },
});
```

Alternatively, you can join the parameters of the `find` function into an object before passing it to `httpClient`:

```
const params: HttpParams = {
  cadnum, 
  pagesize,
  startid,
  // other parameters 
};

return this.httpClient.get(url, { 
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  params, 
});
```

Comment: I got this error: `No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | string[]'.ts(2769)
http.d.ts(1082, 5): The last overload is declared here.` On pagesize parameter here: ` {
        params: {
          cadnum,
          pagesize,
          startid,
        },
      }`

Comment: Second argument is `header` then options, only then parameters

Comment: Also parameters should by HttpParams type

Comment: Hmm.. strange. I have not used Angular in a long time, but I have not gotten this error. Could it be because `pagesize` is a number? Have you tried using toString() on it?

Comment: Yes, it is number, but I must send this as number

Comment: It doesn't matter, because it will get serialised as a string in the url. That's why it is find to convert it to a string. You may refer to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23856

Answer (score -1):

Modify your function which shall take array as input,Then loop for each value and set your url for the same.

```
public find(
    parameters: any[]
  ): Observable<any> {
    let url = "";

parameters.forEach(function (value) {

if (value) {
       url+= "&"+value+"=" + value;  
    }
});

}
```